# Dynamic programming in Aerospace Engineering Problems

Tags: dynamic-programming

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Computer_programming), Dynamic Programming

> has found applications in numerous fields, from aerospace engineering to economics.

What are some example problems solved by DP in Aerospace Engineering?
Maybe something with optimizing launch trajectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic programming is a fundamental core of aerospace vehicles, corporations typically don't want to disclose information like this as it is their intellectual property.

However, there are many scholarly articles that overview how dynamic programming affects aerospace vehicles

Here's even a book on it: https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=MIdp-9rbYSQC&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=dynamic+programming+in+aerospace&ots=K6BSIMGze4&sig=VMDcLYNTYWuUcv87D6zqGejfhOA#v=onepage&q=dynamic%20programming%20in%20aerospace&f=false

I would assume that they are used in other systems besides just launch trajectory.